# Access the lastResult in flex 4

Tags: apache-flex

I follow the wizard to create a http service to connect to a php script. The script fetches some random record from the database.

The label definition is:

```
<s:Label id="label2" x="556" y="136" width="75" height="71"
         creationComplete="label2_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
         text="{GetQstResult2.lastResult}"/>

protected function label2_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            GetQstResult2.token = qst.GetQst();
        }
```

The result is formatted with the wizard into an array, but i don't known how to access the values. Now, when i run the app it shows [object Question].

*Edit1:

```
    <qst:Qst id="qst"
             fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)"
             showBusyCursor="true"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="GetQstResult2"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you see [object Question] is most likely because your lastResult is an instance of a question object, but the object did not implement a toString() method, so it is using the default toString() method defined somewhere in it's object hierarchy--most likely the Object class.

You can define a toString() method in the Question class.  Or you can set the text of your label in a result handler related to the remote call.  I prefer the second approach.  In the result handler, do something like this:

```
var myQuestionInstance : Question = event.result as Question;
label2.text = myQuestionInstance.someStringPropertyOnQuestion;
```

Comment: I don't get it where to put the code. I can say that i have a package called valueObjects and a data Qst service: GetQst():Question which has keys of type string. How can i access these?

Comment: "where to put the code" Put the code in the result handler of your remote service.  Since you didn't provide code for your remote service or tell us what kind it is; it's hard to give you more specifics than that.

Comment: yes, where to put the code, because i don't have a result handler, to put in <fx:Declarations>?

Comment: Then you should create a result handler.  But, I can't help you further because you haven't provided code for your remote service or told us what type of remote service you're using.